# Open file from localhost with javascript

Tags: javascript, uploader

Im trying to add an image uploader on my website. I have a javascript with jcrop (the scrip is not mine, I used the one I found on the Internet); this script takes image file from computer crops it and passes to php. It starts with converting the form output to javascrip file.

```
var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];
```

This is a key line for the script, everything else is derived from oFile. I want to make it avaliable for users to upload pictures by adding a weblink (i already made possible saving image files on the localhost be posting a link); How can I open the image from my localhost with javascript and put it in the same format as oFile variable in the line above, so that my script can work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [binary Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) in modern browsers to fetch a resource as a file:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", fileURLGivenByUser, true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var oFile = oReq.response;
  processTheFileSomehow(oFile);
};

oReq.send();
```

This will work as long as either:

- `fileURLGivenByUser` is on the same domain as the page running the script (e.g., your cropping script runs on `foo.com` and the image link is also on `foo.com`), or
- A target image resource is served with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` CORS response header (e.g., your cropping script runs on `foo.com`, the image link is on `bar.com`, and `bar.com` serves the file with acceptable CORS headers)

So, for your user to use a `localhost` link, the user must be running a local Web server, and that Web server must serve its images with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: whateverdomainyouuse.com` (i.e., whatever domain your cropping script runs on).

If the CORS restrictions are too restrictive (they likely are), you can use a [server-side proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076439/710446) on your host. For example, when you request

```
http://mydomain.com/proxy/http://targetdomain.com/image.png
```

the server does a request and responses with the contents of

```
http://targetdomain.com/image.png
```